# I installed curses but still get the no curses found error

Tags: python, windows, curses

I am completely new with python and want to learn how to code some games, starting simple of course.
So I found code for a snake game and tried to run it. Got the curses error, googled, installed curses and tried again.
But I am getting the same error again. Google has been no help this time so I hope someone on here knows what to do. 
I am running on windows 10 by the way. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you install it? What error do you get? Please check this first https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you may have two pythons installed and you installed module in one Python but run code/script with other Python - if you run code using `python script.py` then install using the same python - `python -m pip install ...`

Comment: How would I have two pythons installed? I just installed the python I downloaded from the site.
Cmd says this about curses: Successfully installed curses-menu-0.5.0 and pip install windows-curses
Requirement already satisfied: windows-curses in

Comment: _Got the curses error_ What error? Always share the entire error message/traceback. How are we supposed to help without any information? I would strongly recommend using virtual environments, or something similar.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Snake.py", line 4, in <module>
    import curses
  File "C:\Users\Python\Python38-32\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'

Process finished with exit code 1